# How do you reload a UIWebView page from JS?

Tags: cordova, uiwebview

When I do `document.location.reload(true)`, I get

```
2015-01-18 17:18:43.642 MyApp[2344:681208] Failed to load webpage with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `location.reload(true)`